# Detecting a very indistinct triangle on a dial using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

So I have a temperature box where I am trying to pinpoint the coordinate location of a small triangle on each temperature dial. Here are the examples of the box with slight variations:

[[image][image][image][image]

I have been able to isolate each dial, get their outlines and centers. I then have an algorithm that will generate an angle measure from the center point and then the eventually found point on the triangle. However, I have been unable, so to speak, "find" solely the triangle using OpenCV. I've been able to outline it and such but cannot figure out how to isolate just it's lines. I have tried multiple shape detection and edge detection blocks of code but have had no luck because its so lightly raised from the actual dial. If I can just get a point on the dial that would be good enough even.

Comment: find the circles, polar transform to get an unrolled "ring" on the knob, analyze 1D signal. -- or work with that screwdriver slot in the middle of each dial.

Comment: Ya so I've been able to find the dials, make a ring around them, find the center and do the calculation for the angle I just can't get the the reference point somewhere on that triangle. And while finding edges of the screwdriver slot would work for 180 degrees it wont work here because it could mean the complete opposite direction exp: 20 == 55

Comment: You can use image matching. Take photos of dials in every state, and then compare them to one on the photo.

Comment: When you worry about the opposite direction, it means that number of candidates is only 2.
Therefore, all you need to do is determine which is the triangle.
e.g. if compare the edge strength of them, stronger one may be the triangle.
Or, checking image correlation between candidate region and other region which is not candidate may have more robustness.

Comment: That makes sense I think, I don't know if I'd know how to put that into code however. If you have an example I can miniplate that would be awesome, if not no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible approaches you can try in order to find the direction of the dial. In this answer I will try it with classic contour detection. However a well trained ML model can be much more robust and reliable in different lighting conditions. But of course it is more effort to set it up.

Let's say that you already have isolated the dial and know its radius and center. Starting from there the straight forward approach would be:

- Prepare the image for thresholding:

  - If the image is of low resolution as in our case, scale it up by some reasonable factor
  - If the image is of high resolution, blur it to reduce noise
  - Convert it to grayscale
- Apply `adaptiveThresholding` or `Canny`, in this case use the first one
- Only keep areas that are of interest:

  - In this case only keep the features in a circular range where the triangle is supposed to be
  - In this case only keep the contour with the largest area
- Derive the result:

  - In this case just get the centroid of the largest contour

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


# read image, scale it up by some factor and apply adaptive thresholding
img = cv2.imread("img_red.jpg")
h, w, _ = img.shape
f = 8
img = cv2.resize(img, (w * f, h * f))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255,
                               cv2.cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                               cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 71, 5)
cv2.imwrite("thresh.png", thresh)

# only examine circle where the triangle is supposed to be
mask = np.zeros_like(thresh)
cv2.circle(mask, (int(w * f / 2), int(h * f / 2)), int(w * f / 3), 255, int(w * f / 6))
thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, mask)
cv2.imwrite("thresh_mask.png", thresh)

# get contours, derive contour with largest area and get centroid
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

if contours:
    m = max([(c, cv2.contourArea(c)) for c in contours], key=lambda i: i[1])[0]

    M = cv2.moments(m)

    if M['m00'] > 0:
        x = round(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
        y = round(M['m01'] / M['m00'])

        # draw small red circle at centroid
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 2 * f, (0, 0, 255), f)

cv2.imwrite("out.png", img)
```

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: So the image that I'm actually manipulating, where it is just the dial, is about 60 by 60 pixels. So while the thresholding works its not as effective. The main problem is still just being able to find a point on that triangle, which thresholding doesn't even fully outline most of the time.

Comment: @Will Can you post the image you're actually manipulating?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's edited as the main image now.

Comment: @Will Thank you! I have updated my answer and hope that I got you right, this time.

Comment: Okay this is looking a lot better. I have run into a problem where it almost always gives the following error: "cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00']) ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero". I don't know enough about this segment of code to determine if a if/else would properly solve this, and what corresponding code would go with it. I have tried a simple if to check for 0, and to ignore that data if so, which allows it to compile, but the resulting point is never on the triangle, so clearly that is not the solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it's more of the thresholding that's the problem because on my end there is a little more noise than you on the resulting mask, and for the blue dial there is a lot more. I’ve tried playing around with the threshold parameters, and it's a little better, but my goal is to have it work across slight image changes. Don't know if you have anything for that either haha.

Comment: @Will Please share the images that run into problems.

Comment: @Markus So I'm using four example images that have slight differences in things such as lighting, angle, and resolution. I can either provide those base images or what the end result looks like for each. I also adapted your code so it would work across pictures, for example I changed "cv2.circle(mask, (30, 30), 20, 255, 10)" to "cv2.circle(mask, (cropped_red_dial.shape[1]//2, cropped_red_dial.shape[0]//2), dial_radius*2//3, 255, dial_radius*1//3)" this way if the image dimensions slightly change it will have the similar mask.

Comment: @Will If you still have problems please add all your 60 by 60 pixel base images at the end of your question so others can reproduce.

Comment: @Markus All the four images are up. Some thresholds work better on other but I cant find a good one that works across all somewhat accurately.

Comment: @Will Thank you for sharing more examples! I have updated my answer, accordingly. The main improvement I added is scaling up the low resolution images to get better thresholding results.

Comment: @Markus Thank you! I think that's as close as I'm really going to get! I have to scale the image back down to it's original size with the circle placement so when that occurs the circle placement is less accurate (I'm assuming due to rounding), but not much you can do about that.